# interpret ntpd configuration used on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

I am still very new to the nptd program so my question should be relatively general. I understand that the program slowly adjusts device's clock rate and syncs to the server time through polling. In the following result, IP address that has a * in the front is the actual time source whereas a + is the backup time source. The backup has a better offset than the actual time source. My question is, in the configuration file, there are 4 servers listed. I wonder which server is the one that the program is syncing with?

```
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.us.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+173.255.215.209 80.72.67.48      3 u   60   64  377   30.713   -0.762   2.808
-64.113.44.55    129.6.15.29      2 u  142   64  274   75.356    3.479   0.970
*144.172.126.201 129.7.1.66       2 u   62   64  375   47.863    2.927   0.418
+108.61.56.35    216.218.254.202  2 u    6   64  377   83.564    1.172   1.423
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, when you run `ntpq -pn` it will tell you which stratum the device is currently synced to, which is denoted by `*`.